# php set permissions file to make it writable

Tags: php, linux, permissions, filesystems

After ages of programming in php this question seems really weird still to me.

I want to make a file writable dinamically to not have problem with permissions in production / development  .... but it still gives me trouble.

Can someone gives me explanation on what am I wrong?

```
// permissions    -- the folder writable by www-data
//drwxrwxrwx 2 www-data www-data  4096 mag 24 12:19 Details

// then the file not writable by the owner
-r----x--t 1 www-data www-data 0 giu  8 12:48 /home/giuseppe/homeProj//Ariprova/trunk/PhpCsv/phpcsv/ConfigClasses/Helpers/Virtuemart2/Details/324-PartsToAdd.json

// then the code

if (!file_exists($fileRequest)) {   // it's found
                throw new Exception ('File non trovato. Nome File completo: '.$fileRequest. ' con cartella '.  getcwd()); 
                }  

if (!is_writable($fileRequest)) {
                $results = @chmod($fileRequest, '0777');  //this gives true 

            }

            $fileReq = fopen($fileRequest, 'w');
            fwrite($fileReq, 'a string' );   // this writes nothing on file

            fclose($fileReq);
```

Comment: Have you tried using `chmod` instead of `@chmod` (which suppresses error messages)?

Comment: also try chmod($fileRequest, 777);

Comment: @Rishabh 777 decimal is not 0777 octal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change `chmod($fileRequest, '0777')` to `chmod($fileRequest, 0777)`. The string `'0777'` will be converted to a numeric value, which will be 777 decimal, which is not what you expect; what you really want is 0777 octal.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the man page for chmod: http://php.net/chmod
You can see that the function "**Attempts** to change the mode of the specified file"

This is because the user that runs the script (eg apache) might not be allowed to overwrite permissions set by the owner of that directory (at least that can be one of the reasons)

**Update**: you can try to go to the parent directory with the owner (or root just to be sure) and change the ownership to the user that you need to be able to do this (chown apache:apache dirname or something like that)